# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package/ Python/ unittesting

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to import the class `Store` from the file `grocery.py` but I am unable to do so using `__init__.py`.

Below is my file structure-

Main_folder:

```
Grocery
    __init__.py
    grocery.py(which contains class Store())
tests
    __init__.py
    test_grocery.py
```

Codes for `test_grocery.py`:

```py
import unittest
from ..Grocery.grocery import Store 

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_cases_getSubTotal(self):
        store1 = Store()
        store1.activate()
        self.assertTrue(store1.is_active())

    def test_cases_getDiscount(self):
        store2 = Store()
        store2.add_points(25)
        self.assertEqual(store2.get_points(), 25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Terminal output:

```
from ..Grocery.grocery import Store 
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: You need to provide the explicit terminal results. What command are you executing and from which directory?

Comment: Does add `__init__.py` in the root folder work?

Answer (score 0):

Your import has to only contain the class_name.py and then import the function or class. Imports are also case sensitive.

```
from Grocery import Store
```

You cannot import from the parent directory unless you modify sys.path

Comment: this is what I get...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Grocery'

Comment: from .. Grocery import Store

Comment: same error as the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
Grocery
    __init__.py
    grocery.py(which contains class Store())
tests
    __init__.py(import TestCases from test_grocery.y)
    test_grocery.py
```

Then run:

```bash
python -m unittest tests
```